# How to move a multiple elements of a table (array) in cobol

Tags: cobol

I have an array which holds a record from a CSV file. Can I for example use the move statement to move elements 5 to 10 out into working storage? Something like: MOVE ExampleArray(5:10) TO WS-TEST. I have been told this is possible instead of having to loop through the array. But I can not seem to get it to compile this way.

Comment: Can you show us your code? That would make it a little easier to comment on.

Comment: here is the line which wont compile: MOVE WSDCSVI-CHAR (1:160)         TO WS-RECORD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using is called Reference Modification.  It is the equivalent of substring() in other languages. Your example code would try to move 10 bytes from ExampleArray+5.

There is a "ALL" subscript concept that is supported.  It has limitations, but it MIGHT do what you want.  Try something like:

```
Move ExampleArray(ALL) to WS-Test
```

Depending upon your compiler, it MIGHT work.  I think the spec limits its use to integer functions, but not all compilers do.

Seriously though, perform loops are very simple and easy, just code this:

```
Perform varying II from 1 by 1
  until II > (Length of ExampleArray-Area / Length of ExampleArray(1))

  Move ExampleArray(II) to WS-Test(II) 

End-Perform
```

Comment: Thanks. I was more than happy to use loops but the analyst keeps telling me to "just do it in a move" looks like that can't really be done!

Comment: There is a Move corresponding that is pretty broken.  Also, you could do a block move IIF both areas are exactly the same size -- but that would break if you ever did maintenance to either area.